# java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: abfs for adls-gen 2 in spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to access adls gen2 in spark java with following configuration properties.

```
fs.azure.account.auth.type
fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id
fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret
```

I have created the blob container and uploaded the file path ex.`https://devbdstreamsv2.dfs.core.windows.net/gen2container/adlsgen2/flat.json` in it using the software "Azure storage Explorer" version 1.9 .I am trying to access the abfs filepath which I am using according to the code mentioned in the document.`abfs[s]://<file_system>@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>/`
But my doubt is we are not initialising abfs filepath anywhere in the runner code.So I am getting the exception " No FileSystem for scheme: abfs ".How can i resolve this issue?I want to know Initialization of abfs filesystem using spark java for adls gen2.

Answer (score 3):

You need a distribution of Spark which has the abfs connector in the hadoop-azure JAR. The hadoop-2.7.x JARs in the normal ASF releases do not, as abfs came out later (2.9+)

Comment: Yeah it is mentioned that Hadoop 3.2+ supports Gen2 in the link below: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction#supported-open-source-platforms